# Azurebot login issue

Tags: azure, botframework

I am trying to use Azurebot in slack in my work place using direct messages (i.e. I did not invite Azurebot to any channel).

1. When I click on the azurebot and type hello, it says I have to login and asks me to click on the url.
2. As soon as I click on the url it takes me to page with "AzureBot [wsfed enabled]". I have both office 365 as well as azure subscription credentials.
3. I typically use regular chrome for office and incognito chrome for azure subscription so that I can have both open at the same time.
4. Here the link opened in regular chrome. But I used my azure subscription credentials because I am not signed into office 365.
5. When I entered my azure credentials in the above page, it takes them but responds with "You have been signed out. You can now close this window."

And I am not able to sign into my azure subscription. Basically I am stuck here. Any ideas on how I can get past this login issue?

Comment: You should see a magic code as well in the respose? Isn't there? What version of AzureBot are u using?

Comment: Not sure exactly how to check the version. But I installed it on Dec 5, 2016.

Comment: No, I did not see any code in the response.

Comment: try using the link provided by AzureBot in an In-private session of the browser

Comment: Did that too. No change in status.

Comment: If you are in a private session; as soon as you enter to the URL the bot provides it will ask you for credentials; and it won't signed you out

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. I entered the url into browser. It asked me for credentials. I enter them. As soon as I enter them, I receive "You have been signed out. You can now close this window.".

Comment: I just tried this and it worked for me. I went to the Bot Directory, picked up Azure Bot and add it to my Skype, sent "login", got the link, entered my credentials and I got "Almost done! Please copy this number and paste it back to your chat so your authentication can complete: XXXXXX" in the browser. In which channel are you trying the bot? What credentials are u using? Work credentials like O365 or personal/MSA credentials? r u sure you are using the login link and not the logout right?

Comment: I tried this in Skype also. Got the same result. This time, I looked closely url. Here is what I am getting (removed the end part): https ://azrbot.com/api/OAuthCallback?error=invalid_request&error_description=AADSTS90072%3a+The+user+doesn%27t+exist+in+the+directory%2c+user+needs+to+be+invited+as+guest+into+the+tenant%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+ee1cbda4-0728-4121-ad75-241844a8283c%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+36b82577-b2e4-471e-a6a4-69328ac8c8c1     Yet, I can successfully login to my azure subscription out side of this bot. I think this is about having multiple azure AD identities.